# How to set outlook so that my inbox can be categorized like web gmail

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail

I am currently having all the emails in one fold called gmail under my inbox folder of outlook. What I want is just like web gmail service, emails are well categorized into, like, "Primary", "Social", and "Promotions". Should I create fold under inbox fold with the name "Primary", "Social", and "Promotions", and my mails then can go to right place?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using pop protocol to get the mail. You will get auto-categorized mail if you were to use imap. In the mailbox setup use imap to get mail from the server.

Comment: I check my settings, it is IMAP.